# How to automate the release procedure of a Vue.js application?

Tags: git, docker, vue.js, release-management

I'm currently looking into a strategy to easily release a `Vue.js` application. For the moment, we have a Dockerfile which builds a Docker image containing the `dist` folder, but the current release procedure is very "manual" (it's being executed by the developer on his local laptop) and this procedure is very error prone.

What I do now:

- manually update version in `package.json`
- execute the following commands in a terminal

```sh
$ docker build . -t ${MY_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${MY_APPLICATION}:${MY_APPLICATION_VERSION}
$ docker push ${MY_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${MY_APPLICATION}:${MY_APPLICATION_VERSION}
```

- create GIT tag

```
$ git tag my-application-version
$ git push origin my-application-version
```

I'm in the phase of automating this a little bit (for example a Jenkins plan?). I'm kind of looking for an alternative to the `maven-release-plugin` (yes, I'm actually a Java developer ;-)) in combination with Maven profiles (the latter one containing a reference to a docker plugin which creates and pushes the image for me)

What do I want to do:

- auto update my version in `package.json`
- auto build and tag the Docker image with the version above
- auto push the Docker image with the version  above
- create a GIT tag

Somebody with experience? How are you dealing with this?

Comment: What I do at my small company, is put all those commands in a shell script. Run `./deploy.sh` and it all works. If any error occurs, the script should fail immediately. Mind you, this'll still take place on a devs machine, and not the cloud.

Comment: @eric-guan: thanks for sharing your feedback! I agree with you as I already started on a similar approach last evening ( I started with a simple Make file ). This release procedure could then be moved to a Jenkins server so the software always gets build in the same way ( same version of Node.js, npm, etc, etc, ... )